# How to configure a weblogic managed server as an eclipse server?

Tags: eclipse, weblogic, weblogic12c

The setup I am trying to achieve-
Two server instances in eclipse, one that allows me to turn on/off the weblogic admin server and the other one that allows me turn on/off the weblogic managed server.

Configuring an instance that refers to the admin server is easy. But I am unable to configure an instance that refers to the managed server.

Eclipse IDE doesn't allow you to create two server instances with the same domain directory. To fix this I just copied the code for admin server in **servers.xml** file(present inside the workspace)  and gave it the port number of my managed server. This way I now have two server instances with the same domain directory. But the 2nd server instance in eclipse keeps referring to the admin server. How do I make it refer to the managed server?

IDE in use: Eclipse photon
Weblogic version: 12c

Comment: If you really need 2 servers, you can create 2 domains anf create 1 instance of each admin server in eclipse.
If you really want only one domain with 2 servers, you can try to first deploy you application with Eclipse to the admin server and then use the console to change the application targeting and select also the managed server. Not sure it will work but you can try.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin I appreciate your help but having 2 domains is not a good option for me, then there's no meaning to having a managed server. Speaking of the deployment, I can deploy my application on both servers, admin as well as managed by setting the deployment from the IDE itself. But the real problem emerges when I want to debug my application on the managed server because the instance in eclipse refers to the admin server only. This is why I need to know how to configure a managed server in eclipse.(just like IntelliJ, it asks you whether it is a managed server or an admin server)

Comment: This dev configuration is not working with Eclipse. Only one server can be used to develop and debug.
Can you tell why you think you need to develop on a managed server ?

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin I am actually working on migrating a project from myEclipse to Eclipse. The configuration I have mentioned above currently exists in myEclipse.  Any changes in the application are done by taking down the admin server. To keep the application still accessible, it is deployed on managed server. The admin server here is more like just an administrator for the actual application.